# tm package installation fails in R

Tags: r, installation, tm

I'm trying to install **tm** package on my Fedora machine using `install.packages("tm")`, but i'm getting compilation error while it tries to install.Here's a snapshot of errors i get,

```
In file included from /usr/include/stdlib.h:25:0,    
                 from /usr/include/R/R.h:28,    
                 from grouped.c:1:    
/usr/include/features.h:313:5: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘&&’ token    
In file included from /usr/include/R/R.h:28:0,    
                 from grouped.c:1:    
/usr/include/stdlib.h:140:1: error: unknown type name ‘size_t’    
In file included from /usr/include/R/R.h:28:0,    
                 from grouped.c:1:    
/usr/include/stdlib.h:337:4: error: unknown type name ‘size_t’    
/usr/include/stdlib.h:367:4: error: unknown type name ‘size_t’    
/usr/include/stdlib.h:471:22: error: unknown type name ‘size_t’  
In file included from /usr/include/R/R.h:28:0,  
                 from grouped.c:1:  
/usr/include/stdlib.h:473:22: error: unknown type name ‘size_t’  
/usr/include/stdlib.h:473:38: error: unknown type name ‘size_t’  
/usr/include/stdlib.h:485:36: error: unknown type name ‘size_t’  
In file included from /usr/include/stdlib.h:497:0,  
                 from /usr/include/R/R.h:28,  
                 from grouped.c:1:  
/usr/include/alloca.h:33:22: error: unknown type name ‘size_t’  
In file included from /usr/include/R/R.h:28:0,  
                 from grouped.c:1:
```

Comment: I'm not sure your 'snapshot' contains all the relevant output.  Can you post the entire error message?

Comment: I've shared the file containing errors. [link to file](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1h7Ull95Nky_TnHgBs9zjwmN7FgvK4FfuPQHcRdcHT_s/edit?usp=sharing)